# Cron executes transfer from HDFS to local, but results not visible

Tags: hadoop, hive, cron, database-backups

Am trying to set up an automated backup of my Hive Warehouse folder (`/user/hive/warehouse/`) to an external hard disk.

I set up a cron for this task which executes correctly (it does not throw any error as per the logs), but cannot see the results in the output folder.

Here are the steps:

1. `sudo vim /etc/crontab`
2. `8 12 * * * root  /opt/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/hadoop fs -copyToLocal /user/hive/warehouse/ /mnt/external_backup/scheduled_data_backup/hive_backup/warehouse/`
3. Save and exit (`:wq`)

The cron logs are as follows -

> Sep 13 12:01:01 user1-data run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[82834]: finished 0yum-hourly.cron
>
> Sep 13 12:08:01 user1-data crond[1845]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
>
> Sep 13 12:08:02 user1-data CROND[83341]: (root) CMD ( /opt/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/hadoop fs -copyToLocal /user/hive/warehouse/ /mnt/external_backup/scheduled_data_backup/hive_backup/warehouse/)
>
> Sep 13 12:10:01 user1-data CROND[83553]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)

Unsure why the final folder does not reflect all the files in the source location. Additonally, I noticed that the existing folders at the destination (`/mnt/external_backup/scheduled_data_backup/hive_backup/warehouse/`) were not updated at the cron's scheduled time of 12.08 PM

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Backup HDFS folder to an external hard disk? It seems you are missing the whole point of HDFS.

Comment: Need to take periodic backups of the Hive tables, so decided on backing up the folder storing the data.

Comment: Having said that, am still a noob in this field. :)
Can you help guide which would be the best way towards backing up the Hive tables, to an external disk?

Comment: The concept of "backup and restore" does not make much sense when dealing with distributed file systems. HDFS allows you to create multiple replications of each data block. E.g. if you set the replication factor to 3 (which is usually the default) then every data block is stored 3 times, **on different nodes**. In case there is an issue with one of the nodes, the file system itself operates in order to keep the desired replication factor.

Comment: You're absolutely right, @DuduMarkovitz, that having a replication factor of 3 stores 3 copies across the different nodes and tends to keep backup copies. 

However, my concern is in the case where some devs (generally, other noobs like me) have ended up taking down the entire system / need to restart the system. Additionally, if the data gets quite old and redundant, need to take backups of these datasets and clear them from Hive.

Comment: Also, we have already set the replication factor as 3.

Comment: "Data lake"?... :-)

Comment: Haha
data lake is a really good alternative. but, it would be easier (maintenance, setup and training) to do a backup we feel.
additionally, would still need to be showing some backups - need to appease client's data concerns.